# Project Setup for Multisite development

Tags: wordpress, setup-project

I am about to develop two websites using wordpress with its multisite functionality. So `www.domain1.com` and `www.domain2.com` should point to the same wordpress installation.

The problem I have is that the domains are in productive use, so I cannot make them point somewhere else until development is not finished. I also do not have (and do not want to buy) two unused domains to create the develop setup, so what I would like to know is:

**Can I setup subdomains for development and change it into »real« domains later on?**

What I would like to know is how to setup the project so that after development is finished, deploying is as painless as possible. The project setup should be close the »real world scenario« it is meant for as possible and I am interested in any kind of hints, advises, links and stuff which guides me setting up the projects.

Which are the pitfalls, where are the »dangerous« parts?

Greetings...

Comment: Do you have a spare domain to set up as "master"? Will this MS contain only this two domains? In this case, 2 domains == 1 site? Are you sure [you need Multisite](http://tech.ipstenu.org/2011/dont-use-wordpress-multisite/)? If sure, take a look at [this e-book](http://halfelf.org/ebooks/wordpress-multisite-101/).

Comment: @brasofilo 2 domains != 1 site, there are actually 2 sites with 2 domains which share certain contents and code, but also have their individual parts... But Thanks for the links, I will have a look at them.

Comment: If you have a domain with which to start up the MS, then it should be easy with a subdomain configuration.

Comment: @brasofilo thanks again for the links, have read them until now and they filled some important gaps I had! So, if I put the things together (perhaps should you write it as an answer that I can accept it): setting up a wordpress on my localhost whose domain is NOT »localhost«, or »127.0.0.1« with two subdomains (f.e.: a.nameforlocalhost and b.nameforlocalhost ) will yield a setup that can be changed easily to my desired result later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the following route:

Install the Multisite with a *sub-domain* set-up in a third domain that will be the *Main Blog* (`example.com`). In your host, you'll need Wildcard subdomains enabled. Otherwise, each sub-domain has to be manually created. With the wildcard, creating a new site is a matter of clicking <kbd>Add site</kbd>.

Then, in `/wp-admin/network/sites.php`, add two sites: `domain1.example.com` and `domain2.example.com`. And develop until they are ready.

You'll need the plugin [WordPress MU Domain Mapping](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) to map Top Level Domains to the sub-sites/sub-domains. With it, `domain1.example.com` will be a fully working `domain1.com`.

After all this is in place, is just a matter of changing the NameServers to point to the Multisite addresses.

---

Well, it seems simple but Multisite is not for the faint of the heart. ***But***, one of WordPress.org wizards, Mika Epstein, aka Ipstenu, has two great eBooks that cover lots of ground. Please, check [the following Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:12615%20110%20101) in WordPress StackExchange where I cite them.

An interesting [case study document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1h1CejwUCKU9SNLtTwHxxZKfGjTWtUkpiMM4wyZdQS8s/edit?hl=en_US).

Plugins of interest:

- [BackupBuddy](http://ithemes.com/purchase/backupbuddy/): paid solution, although it's considered Beta, exporting and importing sites out and in the networks works ok.
- [Add Clone Sites for WPMU (batch)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-cloned-sites-for-wpmu-batch/), in the Repository, although hasn't been updated in a while, still works fine, doesn't exports/imports, but useful for duplicating sites inside the network.